# How to update LiveData from another class?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I have this on my GroupDescriptionActivity class:

```
GroupDescriptionViewModel mFavViewModel;
ArrayList<String> mFav;

mFavViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(GroupDescriptionViewModel.class);
        final Observer<ArrayList<String>> favsObserver = new Observer<ArrayList<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final ArrayList<String> updatedList) {
                if (mFav == null) {
                    mFav = updatedList;
                    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, mFav);
                    partecipants.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                }
            }
        };
```

And in my GroupDescriptionViewModel:

```
public class GroupDescriptionViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private static MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> mFavs;

    public GroupDescriptionViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public static MutableLiveData<ArrayList<String>> getFavs(ArrayList<HashMap> partecipants) {
        if (mFavs == null) {
            mFavs = new MutableLiveData<>();
        }
        loadFavs(partecipants);

        return mFavs;
    }

    public static void loadFavs(ArrayList<HashMap> partecipants) {
        ArrayList<String> newFavs = new ArrayList<>();

        for (HashMap member : partecipants) {
            newFavs.add(member.get("mail").toString());
        }
        mFavs.setValue(newFavs);
    }

}
```

I then have a firestore database change listener in the Source.java file. How can I update my ListView which is in the activity GroupDescription from Source.java?

I tried in Source.java

```
GroupDescriptionViewModel.getFavs((ArrayList<HashMap>) ((HashMap) arr.get(2)).get("partecipants"));
```

but didn't work. `((ArrayList<HashMap>) ((HashMap) arr.get(2)).get("partecipants")` is my new array for the updates.

So I would like the new data to be entered from source via livedata, and my listview to update in real time

Answer (score 0):

if Source.Java has a listener, why not implement it in the activity GroupDescription? or make an instance of Source.java in your viewModel and set the listener interface there and postValue of your MutableLiveData() inside the listener interface and observe it in your activity? from there you can notify your recyclerView adapter.